# change password html form in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Im trying to create an html form to change password in php.
my database is created in easyphp.

Here is the code to I wrote to change the password, when i test it nothing happened or changed.

```
<?
$user_name = "root";
$pass_word = "";
$database = "login";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $oldpassword = md5($_POST['cur_password']);
    $newpassword= md5($_POST['new_password']);
    $confirm_password = md5($_POST['confirm_password']);
    $usermane = $_SESSION['username'];          

$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $pass_word,$database);

if (!$con)
 {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $select=mysqli_query("select * from login where L1='$username'"); 

  $fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($select);
  $data_password=md5($fetch['password']);

  if($newpassword==$confirm_password && $data_password==$oldpassword)
    {
  $insert=mysqli_query("update login set L2='$confirm_password' where L1='$username'"); 
  }

  if($insert)
  {

   echo "Password changed";
    }
  else
    {
      echo "Password  not changed";
    }

  }
    }
     mysqli_close($con);

 ?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="changepassword.php">
 <p>old password<br />
 <input type="password" name="current_password" /></p>
 <p>New password<br />
 <input type="password" name="new_password"/>
  </p>
  <p>Confirm password<br />
  <input type="password" name="confirm_password"/>
  </p>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save Password"  />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Please tell me what is wrong here.

Thanks :D

Comment: You need to do basic troubleshooting, isolate the problem, then come back and ask a specific question. Dumping your code and saying it doesn't work isn't good enough.

Comment: $data_password=md5($fetch['password']); - is password already encripted in db??? if yes you dont need do md5 here

Comment: Can you tell me whats happening at your end? Not updating password or something else? Also is name of your file is "changepassword.php"? trying Leaving action value of your form empty. Like Action=""

Comment: @leemo - "hash them with JS " I hope JS doesn't mean Javascript

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging.

Answer (score 2):

`$usermane` on line 12. Looks like a syntax error. Shouldn't you be getting any errors?

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer

Comment: @robbmj - Given the poor quality of the question, I'd say this is a sufficient answer.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$data_password=md5($fetch['password']);
```

to

```
$data_password=$fetch['password'];
```

you are already storing the passwords as hashes (at least according to your insert statement), when you take the hash of a hash you just get a new hash.

which causes $data_password to not equal $oldpassword

```
if($newpassword==$confirm_password && $data_password==$oldpassword)
{
    $insert=mysqli_query("update login set L2='$confirm_password' where L1='$username'"); 
}
```

also as Eisa Adil pointed out

```
$usermane
```

should be

```
$username
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers and comments, i will try to fix the problems according to your replies. :D

Answer (score 1):

Also usermane and username mismatch

```
 $usermane = $_SESSION['username'];          

 $select=mysqli_query("select * from login where L1='$username'");
```